# Select a row by max(year) and group by name, but also include other values in the result set

Tags: sql, ansi-sql-92

i have a problem with a specific selection in a table. In would like to find all Persons grouped by Name with the max year. But I need also the other columns, for a later join, in the result set.

Furthermore, the id is unordered, so it can not be used in an aggregate function. The query should be database agnostic.

Here is the Table:

[image]

Here is the Result that I need:

[image]

Comment: A lot has changed since SQL-92. Why specifically SQL-92? What RDBMS are you using?

https://modern-sql.com/blog/2018-04/mysql-8.0

Comment: The query is a part of a native query in an java application. Currently we are supporting SQLServer, Oracle, Postgres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below- using correlated subquery

```
select * from tablename a
where year = (select max(year) from tablename b a.name=b.name)
```

Comment: Thx for your support! It Helped.

Answer (score 1):

```
select x.* from tbl x
join (select name, max(year) max_year from tbl group by name) y
on x.name = y.name and x.year = y.max_year
```

Comment: Thx for your support! It Helped.